# Tanstack Query in NextJS API routes

Tags: next.js, next.js13

its just a simple question, not really a needed fix for a problem.
I am using NextJS 13 and I am thinking about to use Tanstack Query.
I want to use the NextJS API routes under
*/api/*

Is it good practice to use TanStack Query inside of the API folder or is it just useful inside of my page files?

I am kinda new to this but heard that Tanstack Query is preety nice and useful.

Thanks in advance